# Is there any way to add custom aliases into pipenv shell?

Tags: python, aliases, pipenv

Is there any way to configure pipenv in a way that it will load custom bash aliases in its shell?

I tried to just put my alias into the `.env` file, but that didn't work.
After that I googled it, but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pipenv shell` appears to take additional arguments that are sent as an initial command to the shell that it starts. A simulated session follows:

```
$ cat tmp.sh
echo hi
$ pipenv shell . tmp.sh
Spawning environment shell (/bin/bash). Use 'exit' to leave.
. .../bin/activate
. . tmp.sh
$ . .../bin/activate
$ . tmp.sh
hi
$
```

---

Since `pipenv shell` just starts an interactive session of the shell named by the `SHELL` environment variable, you can add code to your usual `.bashrc` file to source a special local file on start-up, if it exists:

```
if [[ -f .pipenvshrc ]]; then
  . .pipenvshrc
fi
```

You can also play around with the idea of using the value of `$VIRTUAL_ENV` that `pipenv shell` adds to the environment to choose a file to source.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this directly.

If you're happy to use `pipenv run` instead of a shell alias, Pipenv has a barely-documented [custom script shortcuts](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/advanced/#custom-script-shortcuts) feature; put something like this in your Pipfile:

```
[scripts]
printfoo = "python -c \"print('foo')\""
```

then run `pipenv run printfoo`.